# How to call an external program from a Go template

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-templates

I deploy my kubernetes stuff via the excellent [kontemplate](https://github.com/tazjin/kontemplate/) tool, which allows me to template my kubernetes resource specifications.

I'd like to keep my secrets crypted and only decrypt them at deployment time to hand them over to kubectl.

I imagine achieving my idea like this:

```
$ cat Secret.foo-secrets.yml
{{ shell("ansible-vault view foo-secrets.ansible-vault") }}
```

How can I do something like that with Go templates? Or respectively is there a better/more elegant way to do what I intend to do?

Comment: This does not exist by default. If you control the Go program rendering the templates, you can write and expose a `shell` function to the template. This probably doesn't help you, since I would assume your kontemplate tool controls the template.

Comment: A better approach, though, is probably to use Kubernetes secrets, which are meant to handle this sort of data.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy - as far as I can see Kubernetes secrets are not crypted on my local disc. If they *can* be kept crypted on your local disk and on the fly decrypted when applying them then I'd very much appreciate a pointer to respective documentation. And thanks for the edit!

Comment: First google hit: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/

Comment: AFAI understand that concerns data at rest *in the cluster* and not data *on my disk*? (I have to admit I'm at a loss at deciphering that document). Also using `ansible-vault` is trivial. You `ansible-vault edit file`, get password prompted and that's it. So it's really easy to use. From what I read from the link you provided changing secrets is a really time consuming and complex process... ? So I'd much rather keep processes easy.

Comment: That's about encrypting Kubernetes secrets. If you want to encrypt data on your disk, you have the same problem regardless of whether you're using your hacked-up ansible vault solution, or proper secrets: You still need to provide the disk decryption key to the node.  K8s secrets are just a place to securely store those secrets.

Comment: The problem with your current approach is that it's *completely insecure*. Once you pull that password out of ansible, you've got it in plain text in your K8s definition.

Comment: It's never in plain text on my local storage. `kontemplate` calls `ansible-vault`, gets the decrypted data via a pipe, pipes it on to `kubectl` and that sends it to the cluster. No files with decrypted data created in that process. In the cluster itself the decrypted data *will* be visible. However it will be visible on the cluster anyway since that's a config file and whoever gets to be in the respective container will be able to read the config file anyway. So I the ansible-vault approach looks OK to me? Maybe I can't see the problem you are seeing with this approach? I'd appreciate a nudge.

Comment: It's in plaintext on your k8s cluster. If you trust everyone with access to your k8s cluster (including unprivileged users), then you don't have a problem.

Comment: OK. So how would I go then about calling `ansible-vault` from the template?

Comment: As explained above, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Also, as far as my mental model of k8s goes, it is a kubernetes infrastructure entity that is providing the secret to PODs, However PODs can not at will access random kubernetes resources. So I think the secrets are safe from access from unrelated PODs. Also, interprocess boundaries and file protections still apply. So an unrelated user on the kubernetes machine should not be able to access correctly protected data of the kubernetes infrastructure processes. Is my mental model wrong?

Comment: Your model isn't wrong, per se. But K8s isn't especially bullet proof. Therefore, the safest approach is to assume that any data in your k8s cluster is accessible to all of your k8s cluster.

Comment: You scare me. I'd love to see "K8s isn't especially bullet proof" substantiated (I know about the recent k8s security review). My mental model of security hierarchies is: 1. "anybody with a process on your OS will get to do whatever he wants if he really wants" < 2. "it's a bit harder to escape a container" < 3. "it's a lot harder to escape a VM" < 4. "it's really hard to get into a clean box remotely (excluding zero days)". The k8s secrets case is between 2 (inter-POD) and 3. (inter-k8s), which would be OKish. Provided that k8s is not a sieve of course. Hence my request for enlightenment.

Comment: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-15867/product_id-34016/Kubernetes-Kubernetes.html

Comment: Not too bad. Maybe as a comparison: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2153/NTP.html .
Thanks a lot @Flimzy for enriching me!

Comment: If you're uploading encryption keys with NTP, something's wrong... :P